# Conversion from N by 1 float type matrix to N list

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to plot bar graph based on the coefficient result which has the form of N by 1 float type matrix.

I need to convert 'N x 1 float type' to 'N list'.

For example,

array([[1],[2],[6],[6]) float to [1,2,6,6] list

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to convert that (N,1) to a (N,) array.  The list follows naturally.  With a basic understanding of array shapes, you should know several ways changing the array shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[1],[2],[6],[6]])
a = a.flatten().tolist()
print(a)

[1, 2, 6, 6]
```